# conda install -c anaconda mkl-service : failed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried to run this commend in the cmd and also in Anaconda prompt
but it failed on:
C:\WINDOWS\System32>conda install -c anaconda mkl-service
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64'

someone can help please?
thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are having network issues or need to set a proxy for your network

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
```